# suspected dup account

Tags: discussion

I have no proof, but am kind of suspicious of these user accounts:

[user4567570](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/42601/user4567570)
and
[javasystem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/47988/javasystem)

the later one has had their account suspended in stackoverflow due to voting irregularities.

Both accounts seem to follow a similar patter and sometimes questions related to the same topic.

one of them has a high volume of Questions (in stackoverflow), the other high volume of answers(in stackoverflow). Here in stackexchange, javasystem is "new".

they seem to be "last seen" at around the usual time(s).

weird question with a self answer in a comment seems to be writing to himself
[unable-to-call-trigger-from-the-web-to-case-html-form-in-salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/167793/unable-to-call-trigger-from-the-web-to-case-html-form-in-salesforce) looks like he didn't realize he was logged in with his same account when writing the comment.
[image]

Comment: He did write that comment 6 days later. It could be that they found the answer, then updated their question?

Comment: could be =P, hence the I have no proof. anyways, just pointing out "things"